# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, playframework

I'm using the following script -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function postForm() {

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://10.0.0.8:9000/demo',
            data: {"name" : "test"},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
        })
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="ajaxForm" onsubmit="postForm(); return false; "  method="post"> 
        <input id="test" type="text" name="name" value="Hello JSON" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit JSON" /> 
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The computer i'm trying to access is running the play framework. I am receiving the following error:

OPTIONS `http://10.0.0.8:9000/demo` 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://10.0.0.8:9000/demo`. Origin `http://localhost:8080` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I've been stumped now for two days, can anyone help me out?

Thanks ahead

Comment: NOTE: `contentType` is the `Content-type` header ***sent*** to the server in the **request**!  It is ***not*** the `Content-type` of the response.  It is incorrect here.

Comment: Here's another solution; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin/17098221#17098221

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to make a cross-origin call (from `http://localhost:8080` to `http://localhost:9000`). That's not allowed by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), so the browser is trying to use [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) to ask the server if it's okay to allow the cross-origin call. (That's the `OPTIONS` HTTP request you're seeing.) Since the server doesn't reply to the `OPTIONS` request with headers allowing the call, it's denied by the browser for security reasons.

The SOP applies to all true "ajax" calls (e.g., ones via `XMLHttpRequest`). You can either:

1. Update the server to implement the response to the `OPTIONS` request passing back the headers to allow the call (which will make it work on [most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors)), or
2. Make the request to the same port (I'm guessing there's a reason you're not doing that), so the request is to the same origin and the SOP doesn't apply, or
3. Switch over to using `JSON-P`. But `JSON-P` is inappropriate for form submissions because it's a `GET`, and `GET` operations are meant to be [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation), which most form submissions aren't. So unless this happens to be an idempotent form submission (for instance, a search), using JSON-P would be a hack at best.

Comment: Do you have a link on how to "Update the server to implement the response to the OPTIONS" if you are using apache as local host?