# Jquery ajax not working - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#my-form')
  .submit( function( e ) {
    $.ajax( {
      url: 'http://111.111.111.111:5008/form',
      type: 'POST',
      data: new FormData( this ),
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function (data) {
       alert("SUCCESS");
      },
      error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert("FAILED");
    }
  } );
    e.preventDefault();
  } )


});
</script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form id="my-form">
                    <div>
                        File:
                            <input type="file" name="file" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to submit a form and see if it was successful. The file is being uploaded on my server side and there are no errors, but ajax is saying it is failing (Failed alert showing). I opened the console and it gives the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://111.111.111.111:5008/form. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://111.111.111.111' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So the form is being uploaded because I can see it is from my database. I googled the error and it seems I can use jsonp as a datatype in my ajax. I tried this and it did not work, but I would rather not use this for the security risks and I have no need for that data type.

Comment: I see no justification in down voting  this Question..  hey buddy i see no errors in your code i have checked it. after submitting it is POSTing form content perfectly. I think there is a problem in your service which is written at http://111.111.111.111:5008/form .. ajax waits for response for particular time period if it wont then it throws error event.... OR check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412226/access-control-allow-origin-error you might need to set proxy server in order to redirect ajax calls to actual server(You have to write rewrite rule in order to redirect).Upvoted ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. From my server the response back needs to modify the header. The header needs to allow all origins. Here is an example with Java (vertx.io).

```
ctx.response().putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin ", "*");
```

Once I added this to my server code, the requests and responses work as needed.