# Axios: calling internal API from client result in access-control-allow-origin error

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios

I am working on a project where this project is transition from client -> server -> API to client -> API. That is, the project is calling the API from client side completely.

**What it looks like before:**

Client:

```
sendCode(){
    axios.post("/test",{
    })
    .then(res => {this.setState({
      userID: res.data.userId,
    })})
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Server(Running on node.js):

```
app.post('/test',(req, res) => {
       //Calling APi from there
    axios.post(url).then(response => {
      //Getting the data and send to client
    }).catch(error => {
      //Throwing error
    })
})
```

**What it looks like now:**

```
  sendCode(){
    axios.post(url,{
    })
    .then(res => {this.setState({
      userID: res.data.userId,
    })})
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Currently, it is getting a error with `Acess-Control-Allow-Origin`. However, strangely, i am still getting the data back from the API despite having the error showing up every time.

This error did not appear when I call the API from Node.js. However, it appears when I directly call it from client,

the URL is the internal ESB API that I am calling in my company and I have no control of the ESB configuration

**What I have tried so far:**
I have read the [Community Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) and none of them are suitable in my situation. 
I have also read another stack post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412226/access-control-allow-origin-error) . It suggest server configuration which is impossible to do from my end like i mentioned above. i tried to use jsonp like it mentioned, but it did not work at all.

This is what I have tried following the second post:

```
var postConfig ={
      method: "post",
      url: url,
      dataType: "jsonp",
    }

    axios(postConfig)
    .then(res => {this.setState({
      userID: res.data.userId,
    })})
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Any help is  appreciated

I disagree with the flag down. The post suggested following:

1. set up a server-side proxy, which is exactly how it was done before
   and I don't want to do it this way.
2. Browser Extension: which is not something I wanted
3. Server configuration which is not something that's possible as I explained it.
4. Jsonp, which does not work for me.

Comment: another good resource for you to read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Hi, Dropping in from the review queue for re-opening. Unfortunately the options in the duplicate *are* the only options when it comes to CORS errors. This means that you're out of luck and your question is still a duplicate. 
Yes it's frustrating that you need a proxy server to access an internal API, I've been there too. Programming for the web is Fun!

Comment: @FredStark Hey, thank you for the efforts.  I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @AndrewLohr thanks for the link. It was the first link I found when I encountered this problem and it didn;t help, but still thank you!