# how to allow ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN aka cross-domain on wampserver

Tags: cors, xmlhttprequest, wamp, wampserver

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://webservice.com?param=hahah. Origin http://{domain} is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I get this when I try to make a webservice call through wampserver, how could I enable this on wampserver?

or how may i just jsonP to obtain xml data without javascript throwing an error.

Comment: There is nothing special about WAMP for this. Have you read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: but i need to run it with xml reponses, and I dont think php is doable.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have to enable the headers module first, like so :

- click on the wamp icon in your systray
- go to Apache > Apache modules
- check the option 'headers_module'

And then include this in your apache config:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</IfModule>
```

(in httpd.conf or in the configuration of your vhost)

(Instead of the * you can also specify a specific domain)

Comment: Awesome had to restart the WAMP server several times before this took effect but it worked +1

Comment: @marty where exactly do i need to add the lines of code in httpd.conf file?

Comment: @marty, the access control works with the * at the end but when I put in "me.myspecialdomain.com" it goes back to giving the error. Any ideas what I should be looking for?

Comment: @Faizan : It doesn't really matter where you add it. Just anywhere in the vhost config of your domain.

Comment: @user1794918 : if domain www.b.com is requesting content from www.a.com then in the config of a.com you have to allow b.com. So in your case me.myspecialdomain.com should be the requesting domain.

Comment: @marty how do we allow .woff2 font files to join the party?  for some reason they do not have access like everyone else

Comment: Woffs are not different from other statics with regards to cors policies, so I'm not sure I understand what exactly the problem is you're facing?

Comment: It's not `<IfModule headers_module>` instead of `mod_headers.c` ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hope this will solve your problem -**

To add the CORS authorization to the header using Apache, simply add the following line inside either the , ,  or  sections of your server config (usually located in a *.conf file, such as httpd.conf or apache.conf), or within a .htaccess file:

For all requests -

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

For trusted hosts -

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "your-ip/domain-here"
```

Comment: after I change it in httpd-vhosts.conf in apache into wampserver, the wampserve icon is always orange, do you know what can i do? @Dadaso Zanzane