# How do you Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Wamp?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Wamp as my local server while I test my Angular app.

I am using `$resource` to get some api data from my server but I'm getting a message

```
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myproj.herokuapp.com/api/projects?name=demo.
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

I've searched far and wide on the web but I cannot find a working way to get around this.

Any new fresh ideas? Has anyone overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[how to allow ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN aka cross-domain on wampserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137094/how-to-allow-access-control-allow-origin-aka-cross-domain-on-wampserver/21032371#21032371?s=178bc04b53854de19e1899ab5ccebdd1)

This author got it right.
"You have to enable the headers module first, like so :

click on the wamp icon in your systray
go to Apache > Apache modules
check the option 'headers_module'
And then include this in your apache config:

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

(in httpd.conf or in the configuration of your vhost)

(Instead of the * you can also specify a specific domain)"

Then bring up your browser, and use localhost/filename  to access your files.