# Genymotion localhost access inside a webview

Tags: android, angularjs, genymotion

I have a problem, i can't access to an api i created in my localhost with genymotion.
The api link works fine in the android browser but when i use it in $http.get it doesn't work, i tried logging the error message but it returns null.
Here's my code:

```
$http.get('http://10.0.3.2:80/api/user')
    .success(function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        deferred.resolve(json);
    })
    .error(function(error) {
        console.log("Error: "+error);
        deferred.reject();
    })
```

The console show: "Error: null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, the problem was not in genymotion or in my code but actually in the local server, i had to enable CORS (you can find how to enable cors in wamp [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21032371/4400270))

I also had this problem with my remote server so i have to enable CORS there also.