# How and where to enable CORS?

Tags: jquery, apache, cors

I am trying to get response from an api that is not in my domain.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
               url: "http://stage.developmentcheck.org/api/project_monitoring_detail",
               data:{'project_id':'16'},
               error: function (response) {
                        alert('Error: There was a problem processing your request, please refresh the browser and try again');
                },
                success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
               }
        });
```

So the error says 
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://stage.developmentcheck.org/api/project_monitoring_detail?project_id=16. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.` 
So far I have only used html but since I am using ajax to get data from api, please enlighten me where should i enable CORS and how?
I have tried adding 
`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`
in httpd.conf but it did not work.

Comment: And your code??? post your code also.

Comment: Post your ajax request code.

Comment: i added my ajax request code. thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to bypass Access-Control-Allow-Origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://enable-cors.org/

You can indeed do it via apache. Don't forget to enable it on both sides (server - client). Check the response headers in the network tab of your Developer tools

Server side:

> To add the CORS authorization to the header using Apache, simply add
>   the following line inside either the `<Directory>`, `<Location>`, `<Files>`
>   or `<VirtualHost>` sections of your server config (usually located in a
>   *.conf file, such as httpd.conf or apache.conf), or within a .htaccess file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Did you added it inside a `<Directory>`, `<Location>`, `<Files>` or `<VirtualHost>` ? you can't just drop it in the httpd.conf. The other option is drop it in a `.htaccess` file in the folder you want (e.g. the api folder)

jQuery Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://stage.developmentcheck.org/api/project_monitoring_detail",
    data:{'project_id':'16'},
    crossDomain: true,        
    error: function (response) {
        alert('Error: There was a problem processing your request, please refresh the browser and try again');
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PHP. Just add header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); in the beginning of your PHP-script. Though this will not work if your PHP-settings are somehow messed up or controlled by some strict sysadmin, etc.

Comment: No indication that OP is using php. And what do you mean with "messed up"? Headers can always be set unless the are already set earlier (e.g. in certain frameworks), not?

Comment: @VDP By messed up I meant I've had some sysadmins, for example, somehow disabling configs like access-control-allow-origin through PHP.