# Ajax Request gets blocked in Firebug but works in Genymotion. Why?

Tags: ajax, cordova, cors, firebug, genymotion

I am trying to build an "app version" of my website (a social network).
I am using PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile (i started learning them today).

The app simply needs to retrieve new posts from the website and show them to the user. Therefore I thought a simple Ajax Request would do the job.
So, i created a php test file on the server (URL: `http://www.racebooking.net/it/moto/app/get_post_test.php`), which simply Echoes `Alien contact SUCCESS!`

I've made a simple html page in localhost (on my PC) called `index.html` with a div called `#post-container` and an AJAX request:

```
var root = "http://www.racebooking.net/it/moto"
$.get(root + "/app/get_post_test.php", function(data){
    $("#posts-container").html(data);
});
```

If everything is correct, i expect to see `Alien contact SUCCESS!` in the `post-content` div.
What happens looks strange:

- If i run the app from eclipse using Genymotion, everything works fine
  and i see the message `Alien contact SUCCESS!` -> the AJAX request
  went fine
- If i open the `index.html` file on firefox, i don't see    anything
  and FireBug informs me that the cross-origin request was    blocked.
  He also tells me to activate CORS.

1) Why is that happening and how can i make FireBug work (which is better and faster for debugging)?

2) Am i following the right procedure or i am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [solution from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin).

I just needed to add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` at the top of my php file.