# X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cross-browser

I am developing one system. In that system there is one add item to cart functionality. In that functionality, I am using Jquery $.ajax used. But online server I have facing this error -

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load domain
>   name/add_to_cart.php?item_id=3&hotel_id=2. Request header field
>   X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers."

Can any help me how to solve this error.

**I am using this jquery code**

```
$(document).on('click', '.ordering_btn', function(){
    var item_id = $(this).data('value');
    var hotel_id = "<?php echo $hotel_id; ?>";

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',

      url: 'add_to_cart.php?item_id='+item_id+'&hotel_id='+hotel_id+'',

      contentType: 'text/plain',

      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
      },

      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"        
      },

      success: function(data) {
        $('#cart_msg').css('display', 'none');
        $('#cart_item').html(data);
        console.log(data);
      },

      error: function() {
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have a look at Same Origin Policy

Comment: By default jQuery won't send `X-Requested-With` headers for cross-origin requests. What code are you using?

Comment: I am using this jquery code - $(document).on('click', '.ordering_btn', function(){
 var item_id = $(this).data('value');
 
 var hotel_id = "<?php echo $hotel_id; ?>";
 
 $.ajax({

   type: 'GET',
   url: 'add_to_cart.php?item_id='+item_id+'&hotel_id='+hotel_id+'',

   contentType: 'text/plain',

   xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: false
   },

   headers: {
   
   },

   success: function(data) {
  
  $('#cart_msg').css('display', 'none');
  $('#cart_item').html(data);
   },

   error: function() {
  
   }
 });
});

Comment: @MarkPreston — Edit the question to put the code in it. Use the code formatting button in the GUI to ensure it is readable.

Comment: @Mark Preston Link to possible related issue : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: Why do you have `contentType: 'text/plain',`? You are making a GET request. There is no content to describe the type of.

Answer (score 20):

The error can be fixed by adding

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
```

in the server where ajax call leads to....

Comment: This is most confusing, because my response headers include `access-control-allow-headers: *` (and `access-control-allow-methods: *`) but the browser still says "header ‘x-requested-with’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’". Does a more specific header really work where wildcards fail?

Answer (score 5):

Remove this:

```
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"        
  },
```

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is a **response** header, not a request header.

The server you are making the request to does not allow `X-Requested-With`.

Comment: I follow your instruction but I have received this error - "XMLHttpRequest cannot load domainname/add_to_cart.php?item_id=2&hotel_id=1. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'Domain Name' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: @MarkPreston — Great. That means the problem you asked about is solved and you have a new problem. (Which is that the server you are making the request to is configured to send back an invalid CORS response).