# Jquery Json Api

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a json file `mydata.json`  which is hosted on `www.example.com/mydata.json`

```
    [{"id":1,"name":"site1"},
    {"id":2,"name":"site2"},
    {"id":3,"name":"site3"},
    {"id":4,"name":"site4"}]
```

I am trying to fetch all data using jquery ajax....

```
     $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/mydata.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        }

    });
```

I get an error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." i tried changing `dataType: 'jsonp'` also tried `?callback=?`  ,also tried `.getJson method` nothing worked... do we have to return something from external json file(it is under my control)... is it better to use js instead of json file?

NOte: I can not set header... or change .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Put this: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` in PHP
or change server configuration.

See that: [how to bypass Access-Control-Allow-Origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin)