# Cannot call the php file from angular2 http post request using node server

Tags: php, angular, npm-request

I have rest call like below. Its like cross domain. I want to call the php file which is in the same project folder. But I am getting 404 error. I can able to download the file using error link. That means link what I am giving is correct.

```
return this._http
    .post('/app/php/reports.php', data.toString(), {headers: this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => res.json().data)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Header is defined below.
     private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

Imported files are listed below

```
 import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

Is there any dependencies for npm server to call the php file. I have updated the node sever with "sudo npm install  php-embed" Still I am facing this issue. I hope its a problem with node server to call the .php file. I can able to call the xml file using get request. Here I want to post the data to php file.

Comment: I think port numbers are different.

Comment: No.. I am running on 3000 port.  and getting "POST http://localhost:3000/app/php/reports.php 404 " error

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 uses lite-server its default port is 3000.
Enter the host as wamp/lamp server path (where the php files you placed).
Example: localhost,localhost:80 or localhost:8080
Check the below code.

```
return this._http
    .post('http://localhost/app/php/reports.php', data.toString(), {headers: this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => res.json().data)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Here php file in current folder structure only.. I didnt host any server.

Comment: Cant I call the same app folder php file using npm server ?

Comment: No . You need to install php compiler for execution. The simplest way is install WAMP/XAMPP/LAMP in your compute and place the php file in the www root directory and set the requesting url as the server path. eg. 'localhost/app/php/reports.php'

Comment: I have already same project running on MAMP and I have called the report.php file. But I am getting error like "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/Projects/cwf-06072016/services/reports.php. Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Comment: place the following code in your reports.php page.                    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: Included.. Still I am facing this issue

Comment: So the client side working perfectly. Just provide your php code

Comment: <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo 'dfdsfs';
?> only this much code also doesnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124883/discussion-between-ti2005-and-raj-m).