# Getting Json with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Json hosted online and should be accessed by a link:

```
   {
response: "yes"
}
```

Getting Json on a device:

```
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
 <script>  $(document).ready(function () {
                      var url = 'link is here';
                      $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                                alert(data.response);

                                });
                      });</script>
```

Shows nothing. Please advice.

Comment: Have you added something like this on your php page? $data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);

Comment: @MartHaarman On html page

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` output?

Comment: @Searching it is a phone gap app which opens with Xcode. When I open it locally with browser the app does not runs, therefore I cant test it with browser.

Comment: Sorry my internet connection went all crazy before i finished my post. I meant to ask if you have something like this: "$data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);" on the php page you're referring to.. And like you say you use a html page, could you show some more code?

Comment: Yeap, thats exactly what my php page contains. 
Regarding other code, there is only cdn of jquery and thats it.

Comment: When you open the link you're referring to in your browser, then it does show data?

Comment: sorry format mistake try it again https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

Comment: @Searching I pasted the link and it did worked...means problem is with php side. 
Php:
`$alldata = array('response'=>'yes');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
 echo json_encode($alldata); `

Comment: You could add this to the top of your page: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  This is not rather safe however first it 'll do for testing

Comment: @MartHaarman worked now. thanks a lot. 
Write it as an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the fact that the php needs to grant access. 
For testing purposes you can add this line on top of your php code:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

However this is not safe at all. Therefore you need to write it somehow like this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mysite1.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.mysite2.com')
```

This is all mentioned and explained in here:
[how to bypass Access-Control-Allow-Origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin)