# debugging my website the php file doesn't get loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

my css defines an input of type button submit, and I have a js function for when it gets clicked

```
$(".submit").click(function(e){
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "saveProfile.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    //alert('success function');
                    var messageAlert = 'my_alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    var alertBox2 = '<div align="center" class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    //alert(messageAlert);
                    alert('Thanks :)');

                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#msform').find('.result_message').html(alertBox2);
                        $('#msform')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }

    return false;
})
```

the problem - ajax function always fails 
**the error message:** doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

**What I've noticed:** I can't see the saveProfile.php file on the side panel - does that mean it isn't loaded and if so why? it is located in the same directory as the js file calling/referring to it.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it using chrome/firefox dev tools ? Just go to the `Network` tab and see what is happening with your ajax

Comment: Also add error function.  Never assume that your code will always work. Make a habit of using try catch statement.

Comment: Are you testing it locally, on a machine in your LAN, or on an external domain? What's the full URL you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I consider that the `*.php` files should locate the same directory the js file be called/referred.

And you can also add a header in your request `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')`. but this may be unsafe.you can do more better from [how to bypass Access-Control-Allow-Origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 0):

saveProfile.php file might not be located in your document root. In that case, you should give the relative url of saveProfile.php from your root as the value of url variable.

Answer (score -3):

Use the network tab of the browser debugger (for example [chrome devTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)). There all requests are listed. 
You can see there if the request was successful or not.

Comment: Why is my answer voted down? IMHO it is better to show a user how to debug an application that guessing wild what could be a problem and give solutions to the hypothetical problems.