# How to enable CORS with PHP

Tags: php, cors, wamp

I have an angular 4 app talking to a php script that resides on WAMP (www folder) they are both on my local machine. I get this error logged in the browser when i hit the script.

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

I know its because i am trying to access from localhost to localhost that this problem occurs.

I did a bit of reading and it appears i need to fix it from wamp server. Not sure how to do that on wamp.

Comment: You need to set the headers on your server response to allow `"*"`

Comment: How do i do that on apache

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: Ok that worked...Please place as answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As commented, the problem is that you need to allow all origins from the script.

```
//at the very begining of your php script.
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, I was trying [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47478886/2227743), it did not work for some reason, but I try the one below and it worked:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, PUT, GET');
```