"CORS Policy Blocking Request from Origin 'http://localhost:3000' to 'http://localhost:8000/home'"
When attempting to make a request from http://localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8000/home (redirected from http://localhost:8000/login), I encountered a CORS policy error. The error message states that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing in the preflight response, blocking the request. How can I resolve this CORS policy issue in my Laravel application?
this is my cors.php file enter image description here
'paths' => ['api/*', '/login', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH'],

'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,

this is my react axios

import Axios from "axios";

const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
  withCredentials: true,
  xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN",
  xsrfHeaderName:"X-XSRF-TOKEN",
  headers: {
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  },

});


how to finding this solutions???
i will try to change the cors header & origin but i didn't the solution

Does this error exist if you directly access only /login path from react??

what is the backend that you are using

you have to allow cors from the php side https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478642/how-to-enable-cors-with-php

Change the 'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000'], to 'allowed_origins' => ['localhost:3000'],
