# Can't get data from API with error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php, html, http-headers

I write a new application to get Microsoft Product. A found in `rg-adguard.net` can get link max speed from Microsoft.
So, I tried to create a site same `rg-adguard.net` but require connect to `rg-adguard.net` to get Microsoft products ISO file.
You can see a code look like this:

```
    var url = 'https://tb.rg-adguard.net/php/get_version.php';
    
    $.get(
        url,
        "type_id=" + type_id,
        function (result) {
            if (result.type == 'Error base SQL') {
                alert('Error base SQL');
                return(false);
            }
            else {
                var options = ''; 
                
                $(result.versions).each(function() {
                    options += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('version_id') + '">' + $(this).attr('name') + '</option>';
                });
                
                $('#version_id').html('<option value="0">- ' + selversion + ' -</option>'+options);
                $('#version_id').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#edition_id').html('<option value="0">- ' + seledition + ' -</option>'+options);
                $('#edition_id').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#language_id').html('<option>- ' + sellanguage + ' -</option>');
                $('#language_id').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#arch_id').html('<option>- ' + selachitecture + ' -</option>');
                $('#arch_id').attr('disabled', true);   
            }
        },
        "json"
    );
});
```

I tried on my website is: https://sharengay.com
But it shows an error look like:

> Failed to load
> https://tb.rg-adguard.net/php/get_version.php?type_id=1: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'https://sharengay.com' is therefore not allowed
> access.

How to pass and can get data?

Comment: Hi @smith. I was tried all method. From: <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?> to CORS

Comment: This is an error related to cross origin in the browser. You could use a local url/page in your JavaScript get(). The local page could then use Curl to get the results from the remote location.

Comment: im not a js guy but that worked for me in the past , you could access the variable via php without an issue, so you could access it that way

Comment: The PHP script has to be in the `sharengay.com` domain.

Comment: No, PHP script on `rg-adguard.net`. I tried to send a new request. `rg-adguard.net` return result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Add this at the top of your PHP file:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Also, if you think that is insecure then check this question out: [how to bypass Access-Control-Allow-Origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: I would not advice to set allow-origin to `*`. It's a temporary fix. But better use a specified url.

Comment: OP did say he tried this.

Comment: I was try it: https://i.imgur.com/vZzoMQ2.png