# 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: reactjs

Can you help me, i have a function problematic:
`http://localhost:3000` has been blocked by CORS policy: `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to `no-cors` to fetch the resource:

```
  handleSubmit = e => {
         e.preventDefault();
         const data={
             'username' : this.username,
             'password' : this.password
         }
         fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+'/api/login', data,{
             method:"POST",
             headers:{
                 'accept': 'application/json',
                 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
                 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
             }
         })
             .then(r => r.json());
         }
```

but there is a problem with the url, how do is solve it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDbGz.png)

Comment: You need to enable cors policies on your server, what server are you using as your backend?

Comment: I use node.js as the API, how do I access it? even though in the post man there is no problem

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: Are you using expressJS for the API? @YusupS

Comment: [Obligatory MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your input and answers, this problem has been resolved, and it's running.

this problem is simple, I just add it in pckage.json

```
  "proxy":"http://127.0.0.1:8000",
```

and i am use in axios fatch

```
axios({
        url:'/api/login',
        data:data,
        method:"POST",
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers:{
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
            "Access-Control-Request-Headers": 'Content-Type, Authorization'

        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
    })
```

and it's work for me thank you all (n_n)

Comment: how do you get this to work in production

Answer (score 2):

You can't access resources when the `origin` you are accessing to is not the same as the `origin` you are using.

### Fixes

As commented by @Freestyle09, you need to enable CORS policies in your backend:

In PHP:

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

In node.js (Express):

- Install `cors` package from npm.

```js
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

This should set the headers to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, if you want to specify a host:

```js
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://yourapp.com'
}))
```

Read more from this answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7564919/11555297
- https://medium.com/zero-equals-false/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b

Comment: CORS is not just about `port`, it's about [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin)

Comment: Ok @Maverick and Freestyle09  I will try first

Comment: @rkosegi Yes, correct. But I emphasized what Yusup S' mistake or problem.

Answer (score 2):

In spring boot you can use annotation "@CrossOrigin". You will pass the url of your react app for parameter origins:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000",methods = RequestMethod.GET)
@GetMapping("/courses")
public Iterable<Course> getCourses() {
    CourseService courseService=new CourseService();
    return courseService.getAllCourses();
}
```