Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
I have created a react application whose backend is hosted in Azure. I am new to azure so not sure how to resolve this issue. I referred few other stack pages and got to know that we need to enable cors in the azure web application. I followed the same but nothing helpful. I have attached a screenshot please let me know what am I missing?
The exact error message
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api_link' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 



Your backend needs CORS headers. Azure is a big web host, so how that's done is highly dependent on your application/language/ecosystem etc.

Can you please guide me how to add CORS headers, not a backend person.

@Pixel what are you using for backend? and is your frontend and backend is running on different application on azure or they are deploy in single application?

I created APIs using Azure logic apps.

Remove the added origins and allow access to all the origins by setting the value as * in the Azure App Service=>CORS.

The cors issue seems to be due to the frontend application running at  http://localhost:3000  is trying to make a request to an API hosted on a different domain (api_link), and the server isn’t allowing it due to CORS restrictions.
As @Evert mentioned in the comments, if you are using Node.js with Express as backend, set the appropriate CORS headers in your backend code.

Install Cors module:

npm install cors


Use the  cors  middleware and allows requests from  http://localhost:3000.

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});


Configure corsOptions in the code:

var cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

References:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66274809
